# I accidentally deleted files in xamarin studio under source control

Tags: git, github, xamarin

I accidentally deleted files from my solution (xamarin forms) using source control in xamarin IDE (with github).
My physical files are deleted.
How can I undo things? I found no way from source control (inside xamarin studio IDE).

Comment: So you are using git or not? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: if they are in source control you should be able to find them in your github history.  Have you looked?

Answer (score 0):

if your physical files are deleted then you cannot recover them using git. (may be some data recovery software help you). All you can do with git is to clone it again from upstream repository in github. Use command in terminal

```
git clone "your repository URL"
```

(Note: By using this if there was any work done locally, you will not get that)

Comment: if he had previously committed the files that were deleted then of course he can recover them.  It's entirely unclear exactly what happened.

Comment: yes, off course anything committed to upstream repo can be cloned locally.